# Crystal Report Pie Chart Formula Labels

Tags: crystal-reports

Using VS 2013 and Crystal Report in an ASP.net application and streaming a crystal report to pdf.  The problem I have is my pie chart display.  I want to use the label name of my formulas to be displayed on the pie chart.  So I named my formulas as follows: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J

Each formula as the same formula except that dataset value:

Example for the A formula:

```
numberVar taxVal := 0;

if isNumeric({DataTable1.tjdPYAuthPercenTax01}) then 
    taxVal := toNumber({DataTable1.tjdPYAuthPercenTax01})
else 
    taxVal := 0
```

For the B Formula:

```
numberVar taxVal := 0;

if isNumeric({DataTable1.tjdPYAuthPercenTax02}) then 
    taxVal := toNumber({DataTable1.tjdPYAuthPercenTax02})
else 
    taxVal := 0
```

Under the Chart Export I set the options to only show labels:

[image]

In the "Data" tab the fields are added:

[image]

Everything works except it shows the label as "Sum of @A" for example:

[image]

If I change it to "For each record" then it removes the "Sum of", but it still has the @ before the formula name in the output:

[image]

Output:
[image]

How do I just display the formula name like A, B, C, D, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems the fix was not to use a formula field at all and just use a DataSet values directly.